# Embed a svg shape in d3tip tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with the popular tip library d3-tip.js, an example of it can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). Typically, the tip contains text that is defined dynamically like this:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    html = "";
    html += "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
    return html;
  })
```

However, lets say I have a legend like this:

```
  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

I would like to somehow append a small svg rect inside the d3 toolip. This way when you hover over a graph with different classes (i.e. grouped bar chart) the tooltip will have a svg rect of matching color in addition to the html text. Ideally by using an existing legend variable, as seen above.

If it's not possible, then just explain why and I can accept that as an answer as well.

For clarity, here is a rough idea of what I'm going for visually:
[image]

Comment: I wrote an answer, but here is a friendly advice: get rid of that `d3.tip` plugin, you don't need that. It's way better if you create your own tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to create an SVG inside a `d3.tip` tooltip. Actually, you just have to use the same logic of any other D3 created SVG: select the container and append the SVG to it.

In the following demo, in your `var tip`, I'll create an empty div with a given ID. In this case, the div has an ID named `mySVGtooltip`:

```
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([20, 40])
    .html("<div id='mySVGtooltip'></div>");
```

After that, it's just a matter of, inside the `mouseover` event, selecting that div by ID and appending the SVG to it:

```
var legendSVG = d3.select("#mySVGtooltip")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 160)
    .attr("height", 50);
```

Here is the demo, hover over the circles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

var tool_tip = d3.tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .offset([20, 40])
  .html("<div id='mySVGtooltip'></div>");

svg.call(tool_tip);

var data = [20, 10, 30, 15, 35];

var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 30 + 55 * i
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .attr("fill", "lightgreen")
  .attr("stroke", "dimgray")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tool_tip.show();
    var legendSVG = d3.select("#mySVGtooltip")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 160)
      .attr("height", 50);

    var legend = legendSVG.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10);
      
      legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 80)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", 16)
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .text("Age Group:");

    legend.append("rect")
     .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", "goldenrod");

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 35)
      .attr("y", 40)
      .text(function() {
        return d + " years and over";
      });
  })
  .on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide);
```

```css
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  background: gainsboro;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that, in this very simple demo, I'm using the datum (`d`) passed to the anonymous function by the `mouseover` event. I'm seeing in your question that you have your own data. Thus, change the code in my demo accordingly.

Comment: That's really cool! You explained it well complete with a demo, very nice. Now I see the advantages for a custom tooltip.

Comment: Hey, I ended up hitting a few bumps along the road. For some reason the text is being appended at the very bottom of the page. I believe that is a sign of the `div` being appended asynchronously. Is there some fool-proof way to ensure the `<div id='mySVGtooltip'></div>` always is inside the tooltip? Do I have to set position absolute or something?

Comment: It is always inside the tooltip. Your problem seems to be positioning the tooltip itself.

Comment: Fixed it, turns out I forgot to `selectAll('.legend')` while I was calling the `data().enter().append('g')`, so the elements were just being appended at the bottom.